# Conflicto entre permiso para leer gps y numero de telefono

Tags: java, android, permisos, gps, manifest

Tengo un conflicto que ocasiona que mi dispositivo quede colgado cuando coloco ambos permisos para leer gps y nro de teléfono en una sola actividad, pero cuando pruebo los permisos en dos actividades diferentes todo funciona correctamente.

Aquí parte de los permisos en el manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Aqui el MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvMensaje;
String mPhoneNumber;
private static final long MIN_TIME = 10000; // 10 segundos Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvMensaje = findViewById(R.id.tvMensaje);
    //*     Permission to Read PhoneNumber
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,READ_PHONE_STATE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)   this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
        return;
    } else {
        requestPermission();
     }

    //*     Permission to Read GPS
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
    } else {
        iniciarLocalizacion();
    }
}

private void iniciarLocalizacion() {

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
        return;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);

    tvMensaje.setText("Inicializando GPS");
}

private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_SMS, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS, READ_PHONE_STATE}, 100);
    }
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 100:
            TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) !=      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
            Log.e( "DEBUG-->", "Nro: " + mPhoneNumber );
            break;

        case 1000:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                iniciarLocalizacion();
                return;
            }
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Aqui parte del logcat:
[image: parte del logcat]

Pueden decirme cual es mi error?

Comment: ¿Logcat no registra ningún error? Si registra alguno incluyelo y nos ayudará a estar más orientados para responderte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` y se provoca en este punto, al revisar el array que se obtiene de los permisos, si el array no tiene ningun permiso, no puedes obtener ningun elemento:

```
    case 1000:
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            iniciarLocalizacion();
            return;
        }
```

Te sugiero realices la validacion para revisar primeramente si grantResults en realidad tiene algun permiso:

```
    case 1000:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
  && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    iniciarLocalizacion();
                    return;
                }
```